# Electric field inside an atom thin closed surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

Studying about electric fields and it's null value inside a closed conducting surface, I want to talk about closed **spherical** conducting surfaces and the electric field inside them. Suppose we arrive at such technologies that allow us to create an **atom** thick surface/sheet. This *1 atom thick* sheet is made from some conducting material. Now, if we take a (+q) positive charge and enclose it with a closed spherical shell made out of this atom thick sheet, what will be the electric field inside the shell? What will be the electric field outside the shell? Can the charge enclosed be communicated to the outside world?

Comment: will that hypothetical shell be stable with a charge inside it ?

Comment: Well, i guess we can take the charge as a test charge and then build the enclosure around it. It' should be stable considering the spherical symmetry. What do you think?

Comment: Well I just realised about Earnshaw's theorem. Will that apply here?

Answer (score 2):

The conducting shell rule you refer to assumes continuum electrodynamics (i.e. enough atoms that can be treated as a solid).  The reason the electric field vanishes is in a conducting solid, the  charges within the solid can move to redistribute themselves to align with and cancel the electric field due to the enclosed charge. With a single layer of atoms, you (probably) take away that mobility of charge carriers, and the behavior would be different.  Even saying the word "atom" takes you outside the assumptions of classical, macroscopic electrodynamics.  Every model has its realm of validity based on the underlying assumptions.

Comment: Yes that sounds great. I am curious about such microscopic scenarios!